# How to make gradient follow stroke/path in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, drawing, gradient

I am quite new in Flutter and am not familiar with writing Dart code.

I was wondering if there's any way to make a gradient follow a path/stroke in Flutter.

I know how to achieve path gradients in JavaScript, using the canvas, and interpolating the colours, but I'd like to know if you can achieve a similar result using Dart.

## Example:

I'd like to achieve something like this as a result
this image is from an exemplary drawing app

[image: Example Image]

I tried making a Flutter program which allows the user to draw using single-coloured strokes, like in Windows Paint app, but not gradient strokes.

If anyone knows how to achieve this, or knows of any Flutter library which does something similar to what I'd like to achieve, please explain to me how to. Any help will be appriciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm looking for a solution for it as well.